# date picker js didn't work?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I want to use date picker with js and it's work in some page with some code as same as this page but in this page it didn't work. i wish someone can help me with that

here is my code:

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
        type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
   $('#txtDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
            $('#txtDate').datepicker();
        });

    </script>
 <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/extras/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
<!-- polyfiller file to detect and load polyfills -->
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/polyfiller.js"></script>
```

```html
          <label style="font-size:20px;">期間</label>
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="kasrapro.php">
    <input type="text" id="txtDate" name= "sdate" />
```

Comment: You need to add <input type="date">

Comment: thanks but it's work on another page with same code, and i changed it to this but nothings happened.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was a formatting error. Still there is one error in `console` that is because of your `polyfiller.js`, but DatePicker is working now.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
$('#txtDate').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
}).val();
$('#txtDate').datepicker();
  });
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/extras/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
<!-- polyfiller file to detect and load polyfills -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/polyfiller.js"></script>
<label style="font-size:20px;">期間</label>
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="kasrapro.php">
  <input type="text" id="txtDate" name="sdate" />
</form>
```